# Calculate the number of zeros at start/end of Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series like this:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3])
s
Out[00]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    0
dtype: int64
```

I want to calculate the number of beginning and trailing zeros in this series. So in this case I should get 3 for beginning, since there are 3 zeros before the first non-zero number, and 1 for trailing zeros since there is one zero at the tail of the series after the last non-zero.

**What I did so far**

My solution so far is using cumulative sum

```
sum(s.cumsum() == 0) # begenning
np.sum(np.cumsum(s.values[::-1]) == 0) # trailing
```

But this is very slow for very large series, especially the trailing zeros computation, and I need an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `numpy.nonzero`:

```
import numpy as np

n_rows = len(s)
indices = np.nonzero(s)[0]

if indices.size>0:
    head = indices[0]
    trail = n_rows - indices[-1] -1
else:
    head, trail = n_rows, n_rows
print(head, trail)
```

Output:

```
3 1
```

Benchmark (about 15x faster):

```
s = np.zeros(100000)
s[30000:50000] +=1
s = pd.Series(s)

%%timeit

n_rows = len(s)
indices = np.nonzero(s)[0]

if indices.size>0:
    head = indices[0]
    trail = n_rows - indices[-1] -1
else:
    head, trail = n_rows, n_rows
# 661 µs ± 8.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit

sum(s.cumsum() == 0) # begenning
np.sum(np.cumsum(s.values[::-1]) == 0) # trailing
# 9.39 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Tested and edited*: Works fine with both all-zeros and non-zero cases.

Comment: @jezrael It indeed didn't work with all-zeros, so updated. Bit slower, but still 15x faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiostiy I checked out another plain pandas approach and tested all three versions against a series with 1.000.000 rows.

It turned out Chris's version is about 18 times faster than the original version and 2 times faster than my pandas version. But note, that my pandas version works with the assumption, that the index is a continuous integer index starting from 0 (so `.iloc[i]` would return the same as `.loc[i]`), while chris' version is independent from the index.

```
def test_pandas_version(s):
    truth=(s!=0)
    idxs= truth.index.where(truth, np.NaN)
    #first_one=idxs.min()
    first_one=truth.idxmax()
    last_one= idxs.max()
    whole_len=   truth.shape[0]
    prefix_len=  first_one
    suffix_le=   whole_len - last_one - 1
    if prefix_len == np.NaN:
        prefix_len= whole_len
        suffix_len= 0
    return (prefix_len, suffix_le)

def test_original_version(s):
    suffix_len = np.sum(np.cumsum(s.values[::-1]) == 0) # begenning
    prefix_len= sum(s.cumsum() == 0) 
    return (prefix_len, suffix_le)

def test_np_version(s):
    n_rows = len(s)
    indices = np.nonzero(s)[0]

    if indices.size>0:
        head = indices[0]
        trail = n_rows - indices[-1] -1
    else:
        head, trail = n_rows, n_rows
    return (head, trail)

for func in [test_np_version, test_pandas_version, test_original_version]:
    before= datetime.now()
    for i in range(100):
        result= func(s1)
    after= datetime.now()
    time_diff= (after-before).total_seconds()
    print(f'result for {func.__name__} was {result} in {time_diff} seconds')
```